# PHP to PDF Pagination

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, dompdf

I'm using the dompdf HTML to PDF converter to dynamically generate PDF files based on certain variables.  I have the script creating a PHP file, and then reading from that PHP file to prompt the download of a PDF file using dompdf.

My only problem is that the output doesn't really care when it breaks the page in the PDF.  For example, if I have a table towards the end of page 1, rather than moving the remainder of page 1 to page 2, it will cut the table in half and put one half on page 1 and one half on page 2.

I want to avoid this, and have the script truncate the PDF page so elements are succinctly aligned throughout the document.

Is there a way to do this in CSS, PHP, or some other way?

Here's the script that is outputting the data to a PHP file:

```
 $filename = 'dompdf/www/test/' . $_GET['rubric'] . '_' . $_GET['student'] . '.php';
          $somecontent = "
<html><head>
<style type='text/css'>
html,body {
  font-family: 'myriad-pro-1','myriad-pro-2',Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}


     P.breakhere {page-break-before: always}

table
{
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

td
{
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
}

#header {background:#ffffff url('gradient.png') no-repeat center center;
height: 100px;

}

#text {
position:relative;
text-align:center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id='header'><div id='text'><h3>Upper School<br />";

".$rubricname."</h3></div></div>
Student Name: " . $student . "<br />
Division/Grade: " . $grade . "<br />
Teacher: " . $tname . "<br />
Date: " . $trow['due_date'] . "<br /><br />";

Habit 1: " . $1descrip . " <br />
<table width='100%'>
 <tr>
   <td>E</td>
   <td>M</td>
  <td>A</td>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>Skills and Content</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>" . $grade_exceeds . "</td>
  <td width='30'>" . $grade_meets . "</td>
    <td width='30'>" . $grade_approaches . "</td>
      <td width='30'>" . $grade_doesnotmeet . "</td>
        <td>" . $crow['skill'] . "</td>
 </tr>


Habit 2: " . $2descrip . " <br />
<table width='100%'>
 <tr>
   <td>E</td>
   <td>M</td>
  <td>A</td>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>Skills and Content</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>" . $grade_exceeds . "</td>
   <td width='30'>" . $grade_meets . "</td>
    <td width='30'>" . $grade_approaches . "</td>
     <td width='30'>" . $grade_doesnotmeet . "</td>
        <td>" . $crow['skill'] . "</td>
 </tr>

Habit 3: " . $3descrip . " <br />
<table width='100%'>
 <tr>
   <td>E</td>
   <td>M</td>
  <td>A</td>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>Skills and Content</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>" . $grade_exceeds . "</td>
 <td width='30'>" . $grade_meets . "</td>
    <td width='30'>" . $grade_approaches . "</td>
      <td width='30'>" . $grade_doesnotmeet . "</td>
        <td>" . $crow['skill'] . "</td>
 </tr>

Habit 4: " . $4descrip . " <br />
<table width='100%'>
 <tr>
   <td>E</td>
   <td>M</td>
  <td>A</td>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>Skills and Content</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>" . $grade_exceeds . "</td>
  <td width='30'>" . $grade_meets . "</td>
    <td width='30'>" . $grade_approaches . "</td>
      <td width='30'>" . $grade_doesnotmeet . "</td>
        <td>" . $crow['skill'] . "</td>
 </tr>

Habit 5: " . $5descrip . " <br />
<table width='100%'>
 <tr>
   <td>E</td>
   <td>M</td>
  <td>A</td>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>Skills and Content</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>" . $grade_exceeds . "</td>
 <td width='30'>" . $grade_meets . "</td>
    <td width='30'>" . $grade_approaches . "</td>
      <td width='30'>" . $grade_doesnotmeet . "</td>
        <td>" . $crow['skill'] . "</td>
 </tr>

Habit 6: " . $6descrip . " <br />
<table width='100%'>
 <tr>
   <td>E</td>
   <td>M</td>
  <td>A</td>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>Skills and Content</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>" . $grade_exceeds . "</td>
  <td width='30'>" . $grade_meets . "</td>
    <td width='30'>" . $grade_approaches . "</td>
     <td width='30'>" . $grade_doesnotmeet . "</td>
        <td>" . $crow['skill'] . "</td>
 </tr>

Habit 7: " . $7descrip . " <br />
<table width='100%'>
 <tr>
   <td>E</td>
   <td>M</td>
  <td>A</td>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>Skills and Content</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>" . $grade_exceeds . "</td>
  <td width='30'>" . $grade_meets . "</td>
    <td width='30'>" . $grade_approaches . "</td>
      <td width='30'>" . $grade_doesnotmeet . "</td>
        <td>" . $crow['skill'] . "</td>
 </tr>


<font size='+1'>Comments</font><br />

</body></html>";


          // Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.
          // In our example we're opening $filename in append mode.
          // The file pointer is at the bottom of the file hence
          // that's where $somecontent will go when we fwrite() it.
          if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+')) {
              echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
              exit;
          } //if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+'))
          // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
          if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === false) {
              echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
              exit;
          } //if (fwrite($handle, $somecontent) === false)
          //echo "Success, wrote ($somecontent) to file ($filename)";
          //echo "Success!";
          fclose($handle);
```

Pure HTML output:

```
<html><head>
<style type='text/css'>
html,body {
    font-family: 'myriad-pro-1','myriad-pro-2',Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}


     P.breakhere {page-break-before: always}

table
{
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

td
{
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
}

#header {background:#ffffff url('gradient.png') no-repeat center center;
height: 100px;

}

#text {
position:relative;
text-align:center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id='header'><div id='text'><h3>Upper School<br />Spanish 3<br />
Testing Rubric</h3></div></div>
Student Name: [name]<br />
Division/Grade: Senior Institute/Grade 11<br />

Teacher: [name]<br />
Date: 2/1/2011<br /><br />

Habit Name: test22222 <br />
<table width='100%'>
 <tr>
   <td>E</td>
   <td>M</td>
  <td>A</td>

   <td>D</td>
   <td>Skills and Content</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td width='30'><center>X</center></td>
    <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>

      <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 12</td>
 </tr>


 <tr>
   <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td width='30'><center>X</center></td>
    <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>

      <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
 </tr>

[name] is approaching standards for the Habit Name. </table><br />
Habit Name: tes <br />
<table width='100%'>
 <tr>
   <td>E</td>

   <td>M</td>
  <td>A</td>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>Skills and Content</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>

   <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
   <td width='30'><center>X</center></td>
    <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
     <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 3</td>
 </tr>
[name] is not meeting standards for the Habit Name. </table><br />
Habit Name: test22222 <br />

<table width='100%'>
 <tr>
   <td>E</td>
   <td>M</td>
  <td>A</td>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>Skills and Content</td>

 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
 <td width='30'><center>X</center></td>
    <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 4</td>

 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
 <td width='30'><center>X</center></td>
    <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 5</td>

 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
 <td width='30'><center>X</center></td>
    <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 6</td>

 </tr>
[name] is meeting standards for the Habit Name. </table><br />
Habit Name: test22222 <br />
<table width='100%'>
 <tr>
   <td>E</td>
   <td>M</td>
  <td>A</td>

   <td>D</td>
   <td>Skills and Content</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td width='30'><center>X</center></td>
    <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>

      <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>TESTING 7</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td width='30'><center>X</center></td>
    <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>

      <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 8</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td width='30'><center>X</center></td>
    <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>

      <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 9</td>
 </tr>
[name] is exceeding standards for the Habit Name. </table><br />
Habit Name: test22222 <br />
<table width='100%'>
 <tr>
   <td>E</td>

   <td>M</td>
  <td>A</td>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>Skills and Content</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>

   <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
 <td width='30'><center>X</center></td>
    <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 10</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>

   <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
 <td width='30'><center>X</center></td>
    <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
      <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 11</td>
 </tr>
[name] is exceeding standards for the Habit Name. </table><br />
Habit Name: test22222 <br />

<table width='100%'>
 <tr>
   <td>E</td>
   <td>M</td>
  <td>A</td>
   <td>D</td>
   <td>Skills and Content</td>

 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td width='30'><center>X</center></td>
    <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
     <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 12</td>

 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td width='30'><center>X</center></td>
    <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
     <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 13</td>

 </tr>
[name] is exceeding standards for the Habit Name. </table><br />

Habit Name: test22222 <br />
<table width='100%'>
 <tr>
   <td>E</td>
   <td>M</td>
  <td>A</td>

   <td>D</td>
   <td>Skills and Content</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td width='30'><center>X</center></td>
    <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>

      <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 14</td>
 </tr>
[name] is exceeding standards for the Habit Name. </table>
<P CLASS='breakhere'>

<font size='+1'>Comments</font><br />This is testing a large comment. 

</body></html>
```

Comment: What version of dompdf? What paper size are you using? Can you provide a sample of your pure HTML output that I can feed to dompdf to test with?

Comment: What reason is there to convert HTML to PDF? (no, not for having a single file: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML)

Comment: @thirtydot -- I updated the original post to include the pure HTML output (second block of code)

Paper size should be 8 1/2 x 11

dompdf version is dompdf_0-6-0_beta1 (I'm pretty sure)

Comment: You're testing in landscape, right?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. When I downloaded dompdf, I rigged one of the table examples they provided, and used that template in my php script (table_01.html in examples)

Comment: Actually, from the looks of it, my page is vertical...so it appears to be portrait mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this to your CSS fixes it for me:

```
table {
    page-break-inside: avoid
}
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
html, body {
    font-family: 'myriad-pro-1', 'myriad-pro-2', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
p.breakhere {
    page-break-before: always
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    page-break-inside: avoid
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #000
}
.noBorder {
    border: 0
}
#header {
    background:#ffffff url('gradient.png') no-repeat center center;
    height: 100px;
}
#text {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='header'>
    <div id='text'>
        <h3>Upper School<br />
            Spanish 3<br />
            Testing Rubric</h3>
    </div>
</div>
Student Name: [name]<br />
Division/Grade: Senior Institute/Grade 11<br />
Teacher: [name]<br />
Date: 2/1/2011<br />
<br />
<table width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>Skills and Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="noBorder">[name] is approaching standards for the Habit Name.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span style="color: #fff">-</span>

<table width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>Skills and Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="noBorder">[name] is approaching standards for the Habit Name.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span style="color: #fff">-</span>

<table width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>Skills and Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="noBorder">[name] is approaching standards for the Habit Name.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span style="color: #fff">-</span>

<table width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>Skills and Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="noBorder">[name] is approaching standards for the Habit Name.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span style="color: #fff">-</span>

<table width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>M</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>Skills and Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'><center>
                X
            </center></td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width='30'>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="noBorder">[name] is approaching standards for the Habit Name.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span style="color: #fff">-</span>



<font size='+1'>Comments</font><br />
This is testing a large comment.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need, but the problem also is with the line of text that appears directly below the table:
xxx is <something> standards for <habit>

That can't go on the next page, it needs to follow directly after the table.  That text is still inside the table though, so I'm not sure why it's breaking the page. Any ideas?

Comment: Stick the text inside the table properly - at the moment it's not inside a `<tr>` or a `<td>`.

Comment: It's inside the <table></table> tag. Does it need to be in a TD or TR?

Comment: Hmm, I have it inside <tr> tags but it still is breaking.

Comment: @zackt147: I added in my updated test code which seems to work. The `<span style="color: #fff">-</span>` was somehow required.

Comment: Sweet, that appears to do the trick. Is there a way to remove the black border around that text, though? I don't want it to appear to be apart of the table with the border.

Comment: Oh, also: There's a border around the main <table> element so it still wraps around the outside. Any way to counter that?

Comment: I don't understand that last question. Could you explain again?

Comment: Sorry—the "table" element in the css has a border attribute, as does the td element.  While there isn't a border inside of the td, there is a border around the entire table still, so it wraps it. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Still not making sense :D In my latest edit, there is this CSS to do with borders: `table { border-collapse: collapse; page-break-inside: avoid }` and `td { border: 1px solid #000 }` - the `table` no longer has a border, only `td`'s do.